# How will the tilix work in kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I installed tilix in kali linux but when I type tilix in command it gives me
`tilix: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol _D4glib1c5types__T6ScopedTC3gio22ApplicationCommandLineQyZQBo6__dtorMFZv`.

Comment: Compulsory link to [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment.

Comment: But I searched that kali linux is mostly instead of other platforms.

Comment: I see you had an almost identical question closed as 'too broad' yesterday. This one contains, if it were possible, even less information.

Comment: It didn't answer my question related kali linux which I have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

So, it appears you have the same version I had which means you might be updating from the Kali servers. Removing Tilix and installing the latest stable v1.9.3 fixed this issue for me.

Remove Tilix
sudo apt remove tilix

From the Tilix website:

For 64-bit distros where a package is not available, Tilix can be installed manually from the Tilix Github releases section by downloading tilix.zip and following these instructions:

wget https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix/releases/download/1.9.3/tilix.zip
sudo unzip tilix.zip -d /
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/